# Why varnish returns content-length: 0?

Tags: nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have the following setup:

`url -> load balancer -> nginx[1-2] -> varnish[1-2] -> nginx[1-2] (+app)`

where first nginx uses the second nginx as backup if varnish fails.

When I perform `curl -I http...` I get `content-length: 0` response. However, if I stop both Varnishes (6.0.2) I get some real number instead of 0. My vcl does not manipulate content-length and I see no other setup that would suggest it.

Moreover, if Varnish is ON and I perform multiple curls (10678 to be exact) I would get 14 responses with content-lentgh different than 0.

The two questions are:

1. Is `content-length: 0` expected from varnish?
2. Is it possible that varnish fails to setup a connection once in a while and traffic gets routed to nginx directly? No errors in logs, though.